# How in linked list variable is referencing value to previous variable from which it copied a value?

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to learn linked list from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-2-inserting-a-node/) I saw this code:

```
def append(self, new_data):

        # 1. Create a new node
        # 2. Put in the data
        # 3. Set next as None
        new_node = Node(new_data)

        # 4. If the Linked List is empty, then make the
        # new node as head
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return

        # 5. Else traverse till the last node
        last = self.head
        while (last.next):
            last = last.next

        # 6. Change the next of last node
        last.next = new_node
```

In this code Node ***last*** is copying all the value from self.head then after traversing the list to the end where it appends the node in ***last***. In this case how the reference of ***last*** automatically gets to self.head when we use it again for printing the linkedlist.

Like in following code this `arr` won't change then why is this happening in case of linked list?

```
arr = [3,4,5,6]
prr = arr
prr.append(7)
print(arr)    #[3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: I ran your code and got `[3,4,5,6,7]` at the end.

Comment: I don't understand what your second code snippet has to do with the linked list. Standard python lists are not linked lists.

Comment: Note that `=` never makes a copy in Python.

Comment: You would get the result you claim if you did `prr = arr.copy()` or `prr = arr[:]`. Those make a (shallow) copy of the list.

Comment: *"In this code Node `last` is copying all the value from `self.head`"*: no, `last` will be a reference to the node that `self.head` references. It is also a *local* variable, which is unrelated to whatever your another method would do to help you print the list. If that function also happens to use a `last` variable, it is a *different* variable, which will also first be set to the same reference as `self.head`.

Comment: All I can understand that ```=``` doesn't make a copy but is used as reference. Then in such case answer of pr should be 20 ```ar = 10
pr =ar
ar =20
print(pr) ```

Comment: @Psychonaut007 read [pass by reference vs pass my value](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-by-reference-vs-value-in-python/amp/), this may help you understand.

Comment: @Psychonaut007 your example doesn't work. When you did `pr=ar` they did indeed refer to the same object `10`. But your reassignment `ar=20` made `ar` refer to a different object `20` without changing `pr`.